# Programmatically created nodes don't appear unless opened and saved

Tags: nodes

I've written a simple script that iterates over a CSV file and creates nodes in Drupal. All of the nodes are present in the admin interface but do not appear on the site unless I manually click 'Edit' then immediately save. This is a real problem because I do not have time to open each and every node. Funny thing is, this doesnt happen for every node.

A simplified version of my code

```
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {              
    $title = $data[1];
    $address1 = $data[2];
    $address2 = $data[3];

    // Add a node
    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->type = 'store_location';
    node_object_prepare($node);
    $node->status = 1; # published or not...
    $node->promote = 0;
    $node->uid = 1; // ID of author
    $node->created = date('U', strtotime('now'));

    $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
    $node->path['pathauto'] = TRUE;
    $node->title = $title;
    $node->gsl_addressfield['und'][0]['thoroughfare'] = ucwords($address1);
    $node->gsl_addressfield['und'][0]['premise'] = ucwords($address2);

    node_save($node);
}
```

Comment: Not sure it's the root of your problem, but `$node->created` should be a UNIX timestamp, not a formatted date

Comment: Test if cache clear makes your nodes appear. I f neither this nor Clive's suggestion works, it's an interesting problem. Btw they "do not appear" - I guess it's on a lists and in menus? What about direct /node/nid links?

Comment: have you tried the feeds module it can import csv pretty well.

Comment: Clearing the cache didn't appear to make a difference. The nodes are present in the admin > content list but not in a list I generate on the site until I open and save the node manually. Doesn't date('U') return a unix timestamp anyway? I'll try just strtotime()

Comment: How are you generating list of content in site? Are you using views or any custom module? You can use `$node = node_submit($node); node_save($node)` in your code. `node_submit` will automatically fill up default value of author and creation date.

Comment: @user10051 You're right, `U` does give a timestamp. It's kinda redundant, though, since `strtotime()` also returns epoch time. At least that's ruled out

Comment: `date('U', ...)` returns `string`, `strtotime()` returns `int`. So yes and no, both returns timestamp, but their return values are `==`, not `===`. @Clive can you tell if it can make a difference?

Comment: @Mołot Won't make a difference, there's no equality checking done on the created property (wouldn't make sense for there to be, unless it's checking against zero which it isn't here)

Comment: @Clive I meant saving `string` when DB expects `int` - I'm not sure if it can create trouble or not.

Comment: @Mołot Nah, this is PHP/PDO - it ain't that picky ;)

Comment: I'll try `$node = node_submit($node); node_save($node)`. Strangely enough, when I tried my script (without changes) on the live site instead of the dev site it didn't have this problem. I guess I'll have to investigate my setup. Thanks for all the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Use [hook_node_presave($node)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) to check whether you are getting proper values.

Also, try [drupal_form_submit()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7) instead of node_save() for edit